# How do coefficients work in glm function in R?

Tags: r, glm

So i want to make logistic regression. I did this:

```
logistic <- glm(hd ~ ., data=data, family="binomial")
summary(logistic)
```

And the output is:

```
Call:
glm(formula = hd ~ ., family = "binomial", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.0490  -0.4847  -0.1213   0.3039   2.9086  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -6.253978   2.960399  -2.113 0.034640 *  
age         -0.023508   0.025122  -0.936 0.349402    
sexM         1.670152   0.552486   3.023 0.002503 ** 
cp2          1.448396   0.809136   1.790 0.073446 .  
cp3          0.393353   0.700338   0.562 0.574347    
cp4          2.373287   0.709094   3.347 0.000817 ***
trestbps     0.027720   0.011748   2.359 0.018300 *  
chol         0.004445   0.004091   1.087 0.277253    
fbs1        -0.574079   0.592539  -0.969 0.332622    
restecg1     1.000887   2.638393   0.379 0.704424    
restecg2     0.486408   0.396327   1.227 0.219713    
thalach     -0.019695   0.011717  -1.681 0.092781 .  
exang1       0.653306   0.447445   1.460 0.144267    
oldpeak      0.390679   0.239173   1.633 0.102373    
slope2       1.302289   0.486197   2.679 0.007395 ** 
slope3       0.606760   0.939324   0.646 0.518309    
ca3          2.237444   0.514770   4.346 1.38e-05 ***
ca4          3.271852   0.785123   4.167 3.08e-05 ***
ca5          2.188715   0.928644   2.357 0.018428 *  
thal3       -0.168439   0.810310  -0.208 0.835331    
thal4        1.433319   0.440567   3.253 0.001141 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 409.95  on 296  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 183.10  on 276  degrees of freedom
AIC: 225.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

How do i now predict the value using this coefficients? I dont undertand why my variables `(sex,cp,bs,restecg e.t.c )`became smth like `cp2 cp3 cp4`.
In my database cp is a factor that has only `1,2,3 or 4`. How do i use this coefficients to calculate probability of smth that i need if my cp value has now multiple values?

Comment: Google "treatment contrasts".

Comment: Factors are parameterized as contrasts against a reference level, which in your case is category `1`. Thus, the value for `cp2` gives information on the difference (on log odds scale since it's logistic regression) between individuals with `cp=2` compared to `cp=1` (all other things being equal). Look at `predict()` with argument `type="response"` to predict probabilities

Comment: but how do i put regression coefficients in my formula if it has several parametres. I dont understand. 
In formulа it looks like this: z=a0+a1x1+a2x2... 
How to convert these cp2,cp3,cp4 to one coef like a1 for expample?

Comment: Your formula would be: `logit(hd) = -6.253978 - 0.023508*age  + 1.670152*(Male) + 1.448396*(cp2) + 0.393353*(cp3)  + 2.373287*(cp4) + ... etc.`  For all continuous parameters, you replace these with their actual values. For all reference levels of factor variables (Females, cp1, etc.) you simply ignore all terms involving () for that parameter. For any other level, you keep only the coef of the level that refers to it, ignoring all others. For example, just using my ex formula, for a male aged 30 and having cp2, their predicted logit(hd) is -6.25 - 0.02*30 + 1.67 + 1.45 = -3.73.

Comment: And for a female aged 30 with cp1, the predicted logit(hd) is -6.25 - 0.02*30 = -6.85